# How do you use Next.js dynamic with libraries that exports multiple functions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-proptypes

I cannot seem to figure out how to use Next.js's `dynamic()` function to import a class or function from libraries that exports multiple functions.

In my project, I am trying to do this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const { geolocated } = dynamic(() => import('react-geolocated'));
```

The official Next.js docs give this example:

```
//import Highlight from 'react-highlight'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Highlight = dynamic(() => import('react-highlight'));
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: geolocated is not a function
    at Module../components/Map.js (/home/tithos/Web Projects/nextjs-ipeefreely/.next/server/0.js:71:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/tithos/.../.next/server/static/development/pages/map.js:29:31)
```

Which now as I look at it makes me think this is a TypeScript and/or PropType issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As I found out [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13139) it's done like this

```js
const { geolocated } = { 
  geolocated: dynamic(() => 
    import('react-geolocated').then((module) => module.geolocated)
    )
  }
```